# User access affecting onEdit function in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I had a question about the following script:  It works for me, but it doesn't seem to trigger for shared users.  I've read that simple triggers will work for anyone, but installed ones won't. I'm pretty new to scripting, so any pointers in the right direction would help greatly.  Please let me know, Thanks

```
function onEdit(e){
  var copyFromRange = 'Setup!i4:i53'; \
  var copyToRangeStart = 'Schedule!b7';
  copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);
}

function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange(copyFromRange);
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that simple triggers require no special authorization but you also need to know the [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) of Simple Triggers:

> They do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment)
>   mode.

So I would suggest that make sure the person you share your files with have complete access - write mode, not view mode only.